# Phantom CPU usage

Tags: virtual-machine, performance, cpu-usage

I have a bunch of VM's which all are practically the same. All are set up as a clone of 1 reference machine. On only one of them xentop gives me a continues load (idle?) of around 102%. After looking in this machine i found out that htop & top show me some useage of about/around 33/67 us/sy. So far so good, but the process-list below shows me only processes with very little cpu-usage.... How should i find the process(es) which is(are) causing my 100% extra load.....

```
top - 10:59:39 up 39 days, 22:41,  4 users,  load average: 0.98, 0.99, 1.03
Tasks: 169 total,   2 running, 167 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :  0.7 us,  5.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 93.7 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.3 st
%Cpu1  : 31.8 us, 68.2 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  :  1.0 us,  4.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 94.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  :  1.3 us,  1.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  3932304 total,   110508 free,   381108 used,  3440688 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4194300 total,  3755808 free,   438492 used.  1963228 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND        
    1 root      20   0  121160  81292   2300 S   0.7  2.1  39:32.38 systemd
 4774 root      20   0  157720   2356   1540 R   0.7  0.1   0:02.97 top            
  662 dbus      20   0  102816   1212    584 S   0.3  0.0  13:50.90 dbus-daemon
  775 root      20   0  435560   1648    924 S   0.3  0.0   5:55.53 NetworkManager
 6910 root      20   0   54328  16680  16540 S   0.3  0.4  11:47.24 systemd-journal
18122 oracle    20   0  240200   3444   2236 S   0.3  0.1   4:13.63 tnslsnr
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:28.72 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:05.23 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    7 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:18.56 migration/0
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/0
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/1
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/2
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcuob/3
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0  47:55.71 rcu_sched
   14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   4:02.92 rcuos/0
   15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   5:37.21 rcuos/1
   16 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   5:26.73 rcuos/2
   17 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   5:33.05 rcuos/3
..... cut here ......
```

[edit]some typos[/edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I finally resolved this issue myself. If used

```
ps aux | sort -nrk 3,3 | head -n 5
```

And this showed some oracle process with a cpu usage of 96%. I than scrolled down in the top list to find the same process and there it was shown with 0% cpu usage.....

The process didn't stop after shutting down all oracle databases and listeners.

I killed this process and restarted al services. Now everything is running fine.

Strange thing is the difference between "top" and "ps aux" but for now this is solved to me...